# How to init a `HashTable` object which use named parameters?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, initialization, hashtable, named-parameters

We can init a `HashTable` object using the below syntax.

```
var listTinhThanh = new System.Collections.Hashtable()
{ 
    { "key", someObject }
};
```

I want to use the code in such a manner of:

```
var listTinhThanh = new System.Collections.Hashtable()
{ 
    { Key:"key", Value:someObject }
};
```

But that DOESN'T work. Do you have any work-around?

Comment: 1) Why HashTable and not Dictionary? 2) Why do you prefer the second syntax?

Comment: Just one note: Why don't you use Dictionary<> instead of Hashtable?

Comment: `{ { "blah", 1 } }` is really just sugar for `.Add("blah", 1)`. And about HashTable, are you running .NET 1.0?

Comment: @CodeInChaos, Al Keep: I don't know indeed. I just google it and someone recommend me to use Hashtable when need a `named index collection`. Not sure the differences between the two (Hashtable vs Dictionary)

Comment: @ChodeInChaos: I prefer the second syntax since it is more reader-friendly to me.

Comment: The difference is that Dictionary is generic, and allows you to restrict the key and value to certain types. So you get more type safety. `HashTable` is similar to a `Dictionary<object,object>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't a workaround. Such syntax cannot possibly exist in C# because of the `:`. Also the first seems shorter to me, I wonder why you need the second.

This being said I would recommend you using a strongly typed [`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) instead of a [`Hashtable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx). The closest you could get is this:

```
var listTinhThanh = new[]
{ 
    new { Key = "key1", Value = someObject1 },
    new { Key = "key2", Value = someObject2 },
    new { Key = "key3", Value = someObject3 },
}.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Comment: When tried this, I got the error `The name 'Value' does not exist in the current context`, `The name 'Key' does not exist in the current context`.

Comment: @Nam Gi VU, this is LINQ. You need to reference the `System.Core` assembly and include the `System.Linq` namespace.